# 'HttpWebRequest' does not contain a definition for 'GetResponse'

Tags: c#, .net-core, httpwebrequest

I tried every solution and I didn't solve the problem.

```
var requisicaoWeb = WebRequest.CreateHttp("url");
requisicaoWeb.Method = "GET";
//requisicaoWeb.UserAgent = "";\\UserAgente doenst work

using (var resposta = requisicaoWeb.GetResponse())
{
    var streamDados = resposta.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(streamDados);
    object objResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();

    var post = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(objResponse.ToString());

    Console.WriteLine(post);
    Console.ReadLine();
    streamDados.Close();
    resposta.Close();
}
```

In `requisicao.GetResponse` is the error

> 'HttpWebRequest' does not contain a definition for 'GetResponse' and no extension method 'GetResponse' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpWebRequest' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

When I use CTRL + SPACE it only shows  `BeginGetRequestStream()`, `BeginGetRespnse`, `EndGetRequestStream`, `EndGetResponse`, `GetRequestStramAsync` and `GetResponseAsync`

Answer (score 2):

You need the right `using` at the top of your code:

```
using System.Net;
```

Your code should look like this:

```
using (var resposta = (HttpWebResponse)requisicaoWeb.GetResponse())
{
    ...
}
```

Edit:

After some prompting OP has mentioned that they're on Visual Studio 2015 targeting .NET Core 1.0.

As mentioned by [Scott Chamberlain in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48212109/httpwebrequest-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-getresponse/48212164?noredirect=1#comment83408275_48212164) this is the cause of this issue. Targeting .NET Core 2.0 in VS2017 allows you to use `GetResponse` successfully.

Comment: I'm using System.Net;

Comment: What happens if you change the first line of your code to this `var requisicaoWeb = System.Net.WebRequest.CreateHttp("url");`?

Comment: There's something you're not telling us. What platform are you developing for and against what version of .NET?

Comment: I'm using VS 2015(i tried on 2017, and it doenst work) and 
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",

Comment: @VitorNicacio Well you are using a version of Visual studio that does not fully support .net core (It never moved out of RC stage for 2015), and you are using a horrendously old version of .NET Core, It is on 2.0.5 now and the last 1.x version was 1.1.6. Update to 2017, [migrate your project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/migration/) to the new csproj format instead of the now deprecated project.json format, tell it to use the latest version of NETCore.App and you should see a lot more methods available.